# Is it possible to modify an xml file in Terminal?

Tags: 14.04, tomcat, xml

I got the following instructions:

```
sudo nano /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

add a user who can access the `manager-gui`
and `admin-gui`:

```
<tomcat-users> <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/> </tomcat-users>
```

in other words:

I need to modify xml file, rather: in xml document add new xml tag (`<user>`) in existing xml tag (`<tomcat-users>`).

I do not want to do it manually all times and I think about ability to automate this step in terminal.

What is the best way to do it?

Main problem fom me is **how can I add new child xml tag in parent xml tag** via terminal without manual manipulation?

I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

**Solution:**

```
 sed -i 's/<tomcat-users>/<tomcat-users>\n<user username="user" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"\/>/' /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

Comment: Hi There! I'm little confused with the word "manual manipulation". What is there for you to automate when `nano` or `vi` itself allows you to edit an xml file? I'm using Java served VPS and yes, I did edited the `tomcat-users.xml` on my server for me to have access to the GUI on tomcat.

Comment: ok, I'd like to write a script which does everything that need (install tomcat7, modify tomcat-users.xml file) without the interaction with user. make sense?

Comment: try someting like `sed 's!</tomcat-users>!<user userame...../> &!' file.xml > new.xml` or even `sed -i ... file.xml` to change file.xml directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
sed 's!</tomcat-users>!<user userame...../> &!' file.xml > new.xml
```

or

```
sed -i ... file.xml
```

to change file.xml directly.

For more complex transformation, a tool that has xml-parser would be the indicated choice.